MAUI Scroll to an element in the list programmatically
I was able to this in Xamarin.
Xaml
<ScrollView x:Name="dynamicFormScrollView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout x:Name="dynamicFormStack"
                 BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource responseTemplateSelector}"
                 BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding SurveyList}" Orientation="Vertical"/>
</ScrollView>

Code behind
private void ExecuteUpdateUI(int obj)
{
    var elementToBeFocused = dynamicFormStack.Children[obj - 1];
    dynamicFormScrollView.ScrollToAsync(elementToBeFocused, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);          
}

So this code
dynamicFormStack.Children[index] returned Element in Xamarin but it's returning an IView object in MAUI. I don't know how to convert from IView to Element or Retrieve the Element in MAUI.
The objective is to scroll programmatically to an element in a Stack Layout where a list is binded as BindableLayout.ItemSource

Did you try to force cast: var elementToBeFocused = dynamicFormStack.Children[index] as Element; ? The controls in maui implement both IView and IElement interface.

As an answer:
The controls in the maui implement both IView and IElement interface. So you can convert it directly:
var elementToBeFocused = dynamicFormStack.Children[index] as Element

